# Parse/evaluate/generate CrontabExpressions outside of linux?

Tags: language-agnostic, cron, cronexpression

I'm building some software that needs a scheduling input, and I'd really like to re-use the design of crontab because it simply works.

[CrontabExpressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRON_expression#CRON_expression) can be really simple `*/5 * * * *` "run every five minutes" or more complex `2-59/3 1,9,22 11-26 1-6 ? 2003` "In 2003 on the 11th to 26th of each month in January to June every third minute starting from 2 past 1am, 9am and 10pm".

I am not looking to use the linux software called crontab, I'm seeking a way I can evaluate these expressions correctly (for instance, output the next 25 timestamps that match the crontab, or generate it based on some abstracted GUI for the users).

I can't really find any libraries or functions that do this in JavaScript or PHP or even other languages. If they don't exist, what would be a good method to do this? I already know an overly-complicated regular expression is likely to be the wrong answer. I'm having a hard time finding the C [source code in crontab that does this task](http://cron.sourcearchive.com/documentation/3.0pl1-92ubuntu1/crontab_8c-source.html) as well, which makes me believe it might not take place here?

Comment: Ah-ha, it's actually in this crontab source file... http://cron.sourcearchive.com/documentation/3.0pl1-92ubuntu1/entry_8c-source.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To output the next 25 timestamps that match the crontab you could use [`crontab`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/crontab/) Python module:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import crontab

tab = crontab.CronTab('2-59/3 1,9,22 11-26 1-6 ? 2012')

dt = datetime.now()
for _ in xrange(25):
    delay = tab.next(dt) # seconds before this crontab entry can be executed.
    dt += timedelta(seconds=delay)
    print(dt)
```

#### Output

```
2012-01-11 22:41:00
2012-01-11 22:44:00
2012-01-11 22:47:00
2012-01-11 22:50:00
2012-01-11 22:53:00
2012-01-11 22:56:00
2012-01-11 22:59:00
2012-01-12 01:02:00
2012-01-12 01:05:00
2012-01-12 01:08:00
2012-01-12 01:11:00
2012-01-12 01:14:00
2012-01-12 01:17:00
2012-01-12 01:20:00
2012-01-12 01:23:00
2012-01-12 01:26:00
2012-01-12 01:29:00
2012-01-12 01:32:00
2012-01-12 01:35:00
2012-01-12 01:38:00
2012-01-12 01:41:00
2012-01-12 01:44:00
2012-01-12 01:47:00
2012-01-12 01:50:00
2012-01-12 01:53:00
```

There is also [python-crontab](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-crontab/) that provides `crontab` module but with richer functionality (parse/generate).

Answer (score 0):

There is a Java library as part of the [Quartz Scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org) which can be used to evaluate cron expressions quite easily.

The class `CronExpression` yields methods like `isSatisfiedBy(Date date)` or `getNextValidTimeAfter(Date date)` which is very useful.

The library is freely available.