# python checking time without while loop

Tags: python, time, while-loop, task

I am trying to make a python program that makes a windows box pop up at certain times to remind me that I have to do something. Problem is, the while loop makes python crash, is there any way to make python check the time without a while loop?

```
while 1:
    gettime = time.strftime("%H:%M", time.localtime())
    gettime.replace(':','.')

    if gettime in tasks.keys():
        tasks[gettime] = dowat
        ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0,u'ALERT!', dowat, 0)
        time.sleep(10)
        SendKeys.SendKeys("""
                {LWIN}
                l
                """)
```

I tried making python sleep at the end of the loop but it still freezes up.

Comment: The problem's not the `while` loop. Does it crash, or does it freeze up? If it crashes, can you be more specific with what messages you get?

Comment: Why not just put it in [Scheduled Tasks](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569)?

Comment: I wanted to do this as a small project, it just freezes and stops responding

Comment: I fixed your code to what I assume you meant it to be -- is that right? Your indentation was definitely wrong, and I assume you put `gettime` in a variable for a reason.

Comment: Also, I think your "MessageBoxW" call might be blocking execution. Add prints before and after it to figure out whether or not that's the case.

Comment: related: [Python timer script doesn't run when set to long periods later](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013813/python-timer-script-doesnt-run-when-set-to-long-periods-later)

Answer (score 1):

You're going about it the wrong way... You don't need a while loop. What you need to do is get your current time and work out the time difference. Then you only need to call time.sleep *once*.

Here's some old python code I had laying around that I used for something like this. It had stuff around it that I had to cleanup/remove, so it might not work 100%.

```
import time
import datetime

CurrentTime = datetime.datetime.now()

exec_time = "18:00"

val = datetime.datetime.strptime(exec_time, "%H:%M")
val = datetime.datetime(year=CurrentTime.year, month=CurrentTime.month, day=CurrentTime.day, hour=val.hour, minute=val.minute)

if (val > CurrentTime):
    print "val = ", val
    val = datetime.datetime(year=CurrentTime.year, month=CurrentTime.month, day=CurrentTime.day, hour=val.hour, minute=val.minute) - CurrentTime #Calculate dif.

    time.sleep(val.seconds) #Sleep to next event
```

Comment: you could use [datetime.replace(), and should use val.total_seconds(); also threading.Timer() might produce more natural behavior than time.sleep() if computer is hibernated/resumed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12015233/4279)